# .Net WCF How to separate internal and external web services

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf, visual-studio, wcf-binding

We have the following physical architecture:

Web front end runs in a fire-walled DMZ environment.

WCF service layer runs in another fire-walled DMZ environment.

Biztalk ESB layer runs on our core LAN.

Back office service application layers also run on our core LAN.

The WCF layer is the bridge between the UI and the ESB / back office layers.

UI -> WCF is over https

WCF <-> Biz is over net.tcp

So, this requires different endpoints for our external and internal services.

The question is, how best to separate them?

1) a single WCF project with internal and external endpoint .svc classes and the web.config having a mixture of the 2 endpoint configurations

2) a WCF project each for internal and external endpoints

Answer (score 0):

I'd stick with 1.

Have a single project with service contracts, and different implementations for those contracts depending whether they need to address authentication/firewall issues or not.

The different implementations will have different names and address bindings, and the selected service implementation.

You may have a different project that addresses infrastructure concerns, like which service implementations to select for which infrastructure layout.